# How to secure my spring web application using OAuth2.0(spring cloud)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I am creating one POC spring web application with OAuth2.I need to create an authorization server and a client cum resouce-server.I am done with the authorization server. Now I am trying to build a Thyme-leaf based web(MVC) application which is my client as well as resource-server. So the basic requirement is if i am requesting to uri say http://localhost:8080/createCustomer (Returns a model and view) for the first time, it should redirect to the **AS** . After the user logged in to the **AS** successfully it should redirect to the http://localhost:8080/createCustomer with an access token(JWT). In this scenario I am not sure which code flow I need to use and what configurations I need to make. And to make sure again its not a rest end point. My end point returns a model and view which with help of Thymeleaf loads in browser.

These are some of my config files for the client or resource server

```
ResourceServerConfig  class file

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtTokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public TokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("developer1");
        accessTokenConverter.setVerifierKey("developer1");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore jwtTokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(jwtTokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}

Controller

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class CodeClientController {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @GetMapping(value = "index")
    public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView model) {
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "createCustomer")
    public ModelAndView home(ModelAndView model) {
        model.setViewName("createCustomer");
        return model;
    }

}


properties.yml file

server:
  port: 8080

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: client1
      client-secret: client1-secret
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:7070/oauth/authorize
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:7070/oauth/token
    resource:
      jwt:
        key-uri: http://localhost:7070/oauth/token_key
        key-value: developer1
    authorization:
      check-token-access: http://localhost:7070/oauth/check_token
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: trace
    org.springframework: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG

and pom.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.oauth2.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <name>oauth2-client</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now when i hit my uri as said before i get this instead of redirecting to the AS server.
[image: The error message in browser]